# Printing the literal name of a column inside an R function?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, pipe, janitor

I'm relatively new to R and trying to create a function to apply to a list of variable names I'd like to generate frequency tables for. But, the function as I've written it prints the local variable name for the function, not the actual name of the variable.

```
create_tabyls <- function(df,col_name) {
result <- tabyl(df[[col_name]]) %>%
        adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
        adorn_totals()

print(result)
}
```

And then when I call my function with:

```
create_tabyls(df,'AGE')
```

I get:

```
df[[col_name]]       n percent valid_percent
1   43141    3.5%          3.7%
2  810172   66.4%         69.7%
3  309058   25.3%         26.6%
<NA>   57246    4.7%             -
Total 1219617       -             -
```

I don't understand why my output prints as df[[col_name]] rather than df[[AGE]]. Can anyone help me figure out what error I'm making? I'm trying to get it to print the actual value I'm giving to the function, rather than just printing the name of the function variable.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: fantastic - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) as the input is a string

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
create_tabyls <- function(df,col_name) {

   df %>%
       select(col_name) %>%
        tabyl(!! rlang::sym(col_name)) %>%
        adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
        adorn_totals()


}
```

-testing

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$vs <- as.character(mtcars$vs)
create_tabyls(mtcars, 'vs')
#    vs  n percent
#     0 18   56.2%
#     1 14   43.8%
# Total 32       -
```

---

Or another option if we are using unquoted column name as input, then we can make use of curly-curly operator (`{{}}`)

```
create_tabyls <- function(df,col_name) {

   df %>%       
        tabyl({{col_name}}) %>%
        adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
        adorn_totals()


}

create_tabyls(mtcars, vs)
#  vs  n percent
#     0 18   56.2%
#     1 14   43.8%
# Total 32       -
```

---

Or if we need both options i.e. either string or unquoted name, then `ensym` with `!!`

```
create_tabyls <- function(df,col_name) {

   df %>%

        tabyl(!! rlang::ensym(col_name)) %>%
        adorn_pct_formatting() %>%
        adorn_totals()


}

create_tabyls(mtcars, 'vs')
create_tabyls(mtcars, vs)
```